# why close() system call flushing the output?

Tags: c, unix, dup

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int oldfd;
  int newfd;
  if(argc!=2)
  {
    printf("Usgae : %s file_name\n",argv[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
 oldfd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_APPEND,S_IRWXU); // Opening the file in Read/Write mode
 if (-1 == oldfd)
 {
  perror("Error opening file");
  exit(0);
 }
 close(1); // closing stdout 
 newfd=dup(oldfd); //Now this newfd holds the value 1 
 close(oldfd); //closing the oldfd
 printf("\nStack Overflow"); //Now this printf will print content into the file as stdout closed already
 close(newfd);// closing newfd 
 return 0;
}
```

What I'm actually trying to do is just printing "Stack Overflow" to the file using printf()  instead of write() system call.

Its not printing the content into the file. But one thing i observed is that if i remove the code:

```
 close(newfd)
```

It's printing the contents into the file as expected. But I can't understand why. I printed the contents and then only I'm closing the newfd.

Whats the reason for this?

Comment: In order not to write too often to your disk, for example. efficiency.

Comment: Why don't you just use `fprintf(fd, fmt, ...)`?  I'm not sure trying to reuse fd=1 is a good idea or even defined.

Comment: jedwards, I am actually trying to know why this is not working :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's actually happening here is that `printf`'s output is buffered and not sent to fd 1 immediately; instead the buffer is flushed to file descriptor 1 by the C run-time after you return from `main`.  If you `close(newfd)`, you've effectively obstructed the automatic flush that is otherwise performed by the run-time at exit.

If you explicitly `fflush(stdout)` before you `close(newfd)`, your output should appear in the file.

By the way, if you want to redirect a specific file descriptor, there is an alternate system call `dup2(oldfd, 1)` which makes fd 1 a duplicate of `oldfd`, closing fd 1 if it was previously open.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using file descriptors directly, you will want to *avoid* using the C stdio functions such as `printf`. Changing the underlying file descriptor out from under the stdio layer seems fraught with peril.

If you change your `printf` to the following:

```
write(newfd, "\nStack Overflow", 15);
```

then you will probably get the output you expect (whether your `close(newfd)` or not).

Answer (score 0):

`close`, `write`, `open` are [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) mostly done inside the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel); so from the application point of view, they are elementary atomic operations.

`printf` and `fprintf` are standard library functions built above these (and others) syscalls.

Before [exit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit)-ing (e.g. returning from `main`), the standard library and environment (in particular the code in `crt*.o` calling your `main`) is executing the functions registered by [atexit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit); and the standard I/O is (sort-of) registering a call to [fflush](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) at exit time. So the `stdout` is `fflush`-ed at exit time. If you `close` its descriptor in main, that flush fails and do nothing.

I think you should not mix `stdio` and raw `write`-s to the same write descriptor. Consider using [`fdopen` or `freopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen)